# Maximum of multiple Rows and calculating average between them using Awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I want to calculate the maximum of the values in column 8 between rows starting with 1.000, 1.35, 1.70,......(incrementing 0.35)....,120 (14 rows each) separately and subsequently calculate the average between them (i.e. the maximum values) using Awk. Would really appreciate your help

```
1.000 8 .... 0.017947838827838864
1.000 8 .... 0.029306373626373672 
1.000 8 .... 0.018125164835164853
...
...
1.350 27 ... 0.0014171428571428946 
1.350 27 ... 0.0017828571428571971 
1.350 27 ... 0.0017828571428571971 
...
...
120.000 28 ... 0.49277503924646787
120.000 28 ... 0.41021689560439561
120.000 29 ... 0.38946329670329682
```

Comment: Edit your question to show precise, testable, input and output.

Comment: Are there any extraneous leading column values in the data, such as 1.500?  Or are the values that are present in column 1 only the relevant ones?  If only the relevant ones are present, we don't need to know about the increment; we just need to group similar values in column 1 together.  But you should really show what you've tried.

Comment: The values that are present in column 1 are the only relevant ones. Basically I want the maximum 'value of column 9' in rows having a similar 'column 1 value' and subsequently obtain the average among them. Hope I have managed to clarify

Comment: No. It is very simple - Edit your question to show precise, testable, input and output. That would involve getting rid of all the `...`s from the input and showing the associated desired output given that inpu.

Comment: In Stack Exchange, it is often not possible to present the original dataset to be dealt with due to size and formatting constraints.   So sometimes a description with elided data is necessary.   I would have simplified the question, for example, asking about the 3rd column and only showing that many assuming I could extrapolate the answer to my 9 column problem.  In any case, it was sufficient to provide an answer.

Comment: @wojtow: Even (or especially) on Stack Overflow (Stack Exchange), it is possible to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  Creating an MCVE makes it easier for everyone -- those answering, those learning from the Q&A later.  It adds some work for the person asking the question, but not an unreasonable workload; they are asking for free help, and will get it, but the easier they make it to provide the help, the better the help will be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really isn't very hard.  Since there are only three useful columns in the sample data, I've changed 8 to 3 in the code below:

```
awk '$1 != col1 { if (col1 != "") max[col1] = max3; max3 = $3; col1 = $1 }
                { if ($3 > max3) max3 = $3 }
     END        { if (col1 != "") max[col1] = max3;
                  for (i in max) { sum += max[i]; num++ }
                  if (num > 0) print sum / num
                }'
```

The first line deals with changes in column 1.  If there was a value for column 1 before (`col1`), then save the maximum (`max3`) in the array `max` indexed by `col1`.  Also reset the current value of `col1` and set the maximum to the current value in `$3`.

The next line is the 'every line' processing; if the value in column 3 is larger than the previous largest, record the new maximum.

The `END` block processes a 'change in column 1' as in the first block.  It doesn't need to reset the values because there are no more lines of input.  The next line computes the sum of the values.  The final line prints the average if there was at least 1 value to process.

Given the sample data, it produces the answer:

```
0.174621
```

Clearly, for the data with 8 columns, you'd need to map all the threes to eights.

This code assumes that the data is grouped in column 1, so related entries are together.  It would be possible to avoid that assumption, like this:

```
awk '{ if (!$1 in max) max[$1] = $3;
       if ($3 > max[$1]) max[$1] = $3 }
 END { 
       for (i in max) { sum += max[i]; num++ }
       if (num > 0) print sum / num
     }'
```

This is actually simpler than the previous version; it simply looks to see if the value in `$3` (or `$8` in your version) is larger than the maximum associated with `$1`, and if so, stores it.  If `$1` hasn't been seen before, it sets the maximum to the current value; this avoids issues with 'what is the safe value for the maximum — are the values ever negative'.

And in both solutions, if you want the maxima printed, it is easy to do so in the `END` block with a loop such as:

```
for (i in max) print i, max[i]
```

or you can use more ornate print formatting as suits you.  Note that the order in which the keys (`i` values) are presented is indeterminate.  If the order matters, you have to sort the values, either in `awk` or with a separate `sort` process.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of testing, assume the following input file:

```
1.000 8  0.017947838827838864
1.000 8  0.029306373626373672
1.000 8  0.018125164835164853
1.350 27  0.0014171428571428946
1.350 27  0.0017828571428571971
1.350 27  0.0017828571428571971
120.000 28  0.49277503924646787
120.000 28  0.41021689560439561
120.000 29  0.38946329670329682
```

Use the following awk file:

```
BEGIN { initialize(); }
NF==3 { processline($1,$3);}
END { printmax(); printavg(); }

function initialize()
{
    lastselector=-1
    count=0
    sum=0
}

function processline(selector,value)
{
    if(selector!=lastselector) {
    if(lastselector!=-1) {
        printmax()
    }
    lastselector=selector
    max=value
    }
    else {
    if(value>max) {
        max=value
    }
    }
}

function printmax()
{
    print "selector=" lastselector "  max=" max
    sum=sum+max
    count=count+1
}

function printavg()
{
    avg=sum/count
    print "avgmax=" avg
}
```

The results are:

```
awk -f test.awk test.dat
selector=1.000  max=0.029306373626373672
selector=1.350  max=0.0017828571428571971
selector=120.000  max=0.49277503924646787
avgmax=0.174621
```

To adapt to your problem, modify $3 to be $8 (or whatever column you want) and set the NF= test to be the expected total number of columns in your file.  (This pattern is just to exclude other lines that don't contain data)  Failure to set that right would result in no lines being processed and a divide by zero error.   This code assumes that your input has all the same values for column 1 grouped together in rows.

Hope this helps.   And BTW, your example was sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Input**

```
$ cat file
1.000 8  0.017947838827838864
1.000 8  0.029306373626373672
1.000 8  0.018125164835164853
1.350 27  0.0014171428571428946
1.350 27  0.0017828571428571971
1.350 27  0.0017828571428571971
120.000 28  0.49277503924646787
120.000 28  0.41021689560439561
120.000 29  0.38946329670329682
```

**Output**

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{A[$1] = $3 > A[$1] ? $3 : A[$1]; next }$1 in A{ print "selector = " $1 " max = "A[$1];sum+=A[$1]; c++; delete A[$1]  }END{print "Average  = ", sum/c}' file file
selector = 1.000 max = 0.029306373626373672
selector = 1.350 max = 0.0017828571428571971
selector = 120.000 max = 0.49277503924646787
Average  =  0.174621
```

**Better readable version:**

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{
               # If filed3 ($3) is greater than array A element where index being field1,
               # then A[$1] = $3, otherwise array A value will not change
               A[$1] = $3 > A[$1] ? $3 : A[$1]

               # Stop processing go to next line
               next 
             }

              # Here we read same file once again
              # if index key $1 exists in array A
      $1 in A{ 
               # print field1 and max value
               print "selector = " $1 " max = "A[$1]

               # sum of max 
               sum+=A[$1] 

               # Count
               c++

               # Delete element of array
               delete A[$1]  
             }

          END{ 
                # Print Average finally
                print "Average  = ", sum/c
             }
     ' file file
```

**Other Way - processing in END block, if output order doesn't matter**

```
 awk '{
            A[$1] = $3 > A[$1] ? $3 : A[$1]
      }
   END{
            for(i in A)
            {
               print "selector = " i " max = "A[i]
               sum+=A[i]  
            }
               print "Average  = ", sum/length(A)
      }
     ' file
```

Comment: It is always worth avoiding the need to read the file twice when it's possible to do so.